# Textbook Recommendation regarding Spectral Measure

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation

For starters, I've studied following maths:

> Linear Algebra 
> Rudin's PMA 
> Stein's Real Analysis (upto ch4: Intro to Hilbert Space) 
> other basic statistics subjects (mathematical statistics, regression analysis, etc)

I was given the [following paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.08560) regarding high-dimensional least squares, and I was trying to understand the **theorem 1** of the paper (appendix C.2 page 39).

The thing is, I was stuck to the following statement.

$$V_X(\hat \beta;\beta) = \frac{\sigma^2}{p}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{t_i} 
= \frac{\sigma^2 n}{p}\int \frac{1}{t}dF_{XX^T/p}(t),$$
*where $F_{XX^T/p}$ is the **spectral measure** of $XX^T/p$.*

I've seen the term **spectral measure** for the first time, so I tried to look several functional analysis books (including Rudin's functional analysis, and Kreyszig's  Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications), but I failed to find the term **spctral measure**.

It would be grateful if you recommend some textbooks covering **spectral measure**. If my math basic is not enough to understand it, could you also recommend me about what I should study before understanding **spectral measure**?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you do a Google search for spectral measure of an operator you get a ton of useful links.

Comment: In Rudins book spectral measures are called "resolution of the identity". They are defined in section 12.17. Kreyzig calls them "spectral family" they are defined in section 9.7 (Althought Kreyzig works with spectral measures from a more basic point of view using the Riemann-Stiltjes integral).

Comment: You can also check section 2.7 of "A Short Course on Spectral Theory" by William Arveson